# C# on Linux - Anyone got an opinion based on experience using mono?

Tags: c#, java

Is it worthwhile learning C# if you are a Linux user? There is Mono but it seems destined to always be behind the curve with the constant threat of MS action if they start to lose money.

Currently I am leaning more towards Java as its is fully GPLed and there are no major threats of software patents. It already has a big oss community behind it and has a solid reputation on the server whereas C# still needs to prove itself there.

The big advantage for C# programmers is that they are cheaper than Java developers. I also wonder exactly how portable C# code is though. Can one simply take a C# app written to target Mono and run it on windows?

Comment: Great, I misspelled "spelling" in my edit summary. =)

Comment: Everything asked in this question has been discussed at length here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mono

Comment: Isn't being "cheaper" *bad* for the programmers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've written a number of C# command-line programs, specifically to run as distributed simulation engines, that were targeted for Ubuntu. They work perfectly there or on Windows.

It's hard to say what the future holds, but C# is a powerful language and I think it's worth learning even just for our personal growth. I despise Windows myself but have been writing C# for a while (for Windows mostly) since it pays the bills.

Novell uses Mono extensively for their Linux applications and I think that their relationship with Microsoft adds some weight to the idea that .NET for Linux will stick around.

[Here's a list](http://www.mono-project.com/Companies_Using_Mono) of some of the companies using Mono.

Answer (score 2):

> "on the server whereas C# still needs
>   to proof itself there"

You do know MySpace is built ontop of ASP.NET, right? Millions of hits a day running off a C# backend.

Comment: PlentyofFish too and they do it all on one or two servers.

Comment: and, needless to say, Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the flame-bait, but I've personally had more portability success with mono, than java. Not a blanket statement, just my experience.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked and answered many times on SO.

[Is Mono ready for prime time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450/is-mono-ready-for-prime-time)

[Why Use Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573982/why-use-mono)

Answer (score 0):

Given your scenario, **me personally** I would learn Java, as you will find the transition into C# further down the line, quite smooth.  Also having Java under your belt is a very good thing.  I would say Java is much more portable than C# although you have the option of using the Compact Framework, which will be quicker to bootstrap with your program.

Answer (score 0):

I work for a company that uses both Java and C#. I prefer C# because I think Visual Studio blows away Eclipse, and I just like the language better. However, I think you might do better learning Java in your case. You have more flexibility both for your project and career-wise. You can learn C# anytime.

Comment: I prefer Visual Studio over Eclipse -- but I prefer SharpDevelop over Visual Studio. Have you tried it before?

Answer (score 0):

C# is a nice language, and I find it much easier to work with than C/C++, especially for GTK applications.

I also think that learning C# would be a much better investment than learning Java. I'm saying this for no other reason than my personal taste, but I also honestly and objectively believe that C# will have a better future than Java.

As for running Mono apps on Windows, you can usually do this without a hassle, but if it's a GUI application, you will either have to create a Windows version that uses Winforms, or your users will have to install GTK for Windows. Either way, your applications will have a much better look and feel than Java applications on both platforms.

Finally, I don't think M$ will take legal action against Mono anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

It works very nice. IMHO you should use Mono from the development site ([www.go-mono.com](http://www.go-mono.com)) rather than version provided with your distribution.

Also you could try dry-running it with VMWare machine that is also avaliable on the official site.