# How to fix a System.AggregateException when using Parallel.For loops in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, aggregateexception

I have a loop in C# that looks like this:

```
for (int level = 0; level < numLevels; level++){
    for (int y = 0; y < ysize; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < xsize; x++){
            outArray[y*xsize + x] = SomeMathWasDone(level);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to parallelize this code using a Parallel.For loop, something that seems pretty straightforward, at least according to [Reed's answer to an earlier question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5983664/21981).  So I go ahead and do this:

```
for (int level = 0; level < numLevels; level++){
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, ysize),
                (range) => {
    for (int y = range.Item1; y < range.Item2; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < xsize; x++){
            outArray[y*xsize + x] = SomeMathWasDone(level);
        }
    }
    });
}
```

This code throws a System.AggregateException.  The inner exception is:

```
    InnerException  {"Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds."}    System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

I know that the arrays are the right size, since the code works just fine when it's not parallel.  What does this mean?  How can I debug this problem?  Or should I be doing something else entirely when parallelizing code of this nature?

The inner exception stack trace is:

```
at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length)
at System.Array.CopyTo(Array array, Int32 index)
at MyFunction(Single[] inImage, Int32 inXSize, Int32 inYSize, Int32 inLevels) ... line 100
```

After going to that line, I messed with it to see if that could be the issue.  The line was:

```
float[] theKernel = 
        {1.0f, 4.0f, 6.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f,
        4.0f, 16.0f, 24.0f, 16.0f, 4.0f,
        6.0f, 24.0f, 36.0f, 24.0f, 6.0f,
        4.0f, 16.0f, 24.0f, 16.0f, 4.0f,
        1.0f, 4.0f, 6.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f};
```

And thinking that maybe that wouldn't work, I then tried the more explicit:

```
//outside the function, now a member of the class
float[] downsizeKernel= 
        {1.0f, 4.0f, 6.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f,
        4.0f, 16.0f, 24.0f, 16.0f, 4.0f,
        6.0f, 24.0f, 36.0f, 24.0f, 6.0f,
        4.0f, 16.0f, 24.0f, 16.0f, 4.0f,
        1.0f, 4.0f, 6.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f};

//now inside the function
float[] theKernel = new float[25];
downsizeKernel.CopyTo(theKernel, 0);
```

So could that be the problem, some kind of internal array copying?  How should this array declaration be handled to avoid the exception, if that's the problem?

Comment: @SLaks-- It ends at that exception.  Above it are functions that are pretty irrelevant.

Comment: Huh? What's the stack trace of the inner exception?

Comment: @SLaks-- is this what you're looking for? I'm not sure what kind of information can be gotten from this trace, but I definitely need to learn.  It looks like it's expecting code to execute faster than it is, but that shouldn't really cause this kind of failure, right?

Comment: That's the _outer_ exception stack trace.  The stack trace tells you where the error actually happened.  The top line threw the exception; the second line called the first line, etc.

Comment: The inner exception stack trace will most likely contain `Array.Copy()`, or similar method. Can you post that, as SLaks requested?

Comment: @svick-- it does indeed.  Is this a common enough issue that I should have found it via google-fu?  Because I found nothing on this one.

Comment: The line numbers may sometimes be slightly off. I doubt the line that initializes `theKernel` is the problem. Do you have some calls to `Array.CopyTo()` close by? That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: @svick-- There is a copyto near there; is copyto not threadsafe?