# How to use MMX code in c# for image processing

Tags: c#, image-processing, sse, mmx

I'm writing an app that makes too many 128bit calculations with C#. **(Image processing - 16bit R, 16bit G, 16bit B, 16bit A)**

Can I calculate this 2 64bit RGBA colors in **one cycle**.

Is there any way to use assembly(MMX) code to do that calculations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SSE in c# is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415375/using-sse-in-c-sharp-is-it-possible)

Comment: MMX is antique. The general name for vectorization instruction sets is SIMD (Single Instruction Multiple Data).

Comment: @PaulR That question seems a bit dated. How about recent publications such as http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/07/the-jit-finally-proposed-jit-and-simd-are-getting-married.aspx ?

Comment: Sure, but given that the OP was asking about MMX that question seems pretty modern by comparison. ;-)